# Complex filter in SQLAlchemy - How?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Attribute and AttributeValue are One-To-Many, Attribute/AttributeValue pair and Item are Many-to-Many.
This design is to allow a Item can be attached several Attributes. Now we want to select all Items with selected Attribute-AttributeValue.

We want to select all Items with special AttributeName/Value pair.
Anyway to do this in SQLAlchemy?

```
class AttributeSchema(Base, DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'attributeschemas'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(length=255))
    type = Column(Enum('Boolean', 'Integer', 'String'), default='String')
    is_index = Column(Boolean, default=False)

class AttributeValueSchema(Base, DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'attributevalueschemas'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String(length=255))
    attributeschema_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('attributeschemas.id'), nullable=True)
    attributeschema = relationship('AttributeSchema', backref='attributeschemavalues')

class ItemType(Base, DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'itemtypes'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(length=255))

    market_price = Column(Float)
    attributes = relationship('AttributeSchema')

class ItemTypeAttribute(Base, DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'itemtype_attribute'
    itemtype_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('itemtypes.id'), primary_key=True)
    attribute_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('attributeschemas.id'), primary_key=True)
    attributevalue_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('attributevalueschemas.id'), primary_key=True)
    itemtype = relationship('ItemType')
    attribute = relationship('AttributeSchema')
    attributevalue = relationship('AttributeValueSchema')
```

Comment: It looks like your database schema is not complete. Which table stores the value of an attribute for an item?

Comment: I already modified my original post with Code attached.